# Permission issues - cannot write www-data:www-data /var/www

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

When I set up a site on my server I set permissions to /var/www/ like so:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER var/www/
```

However, when I try and write to my image directory I get a permission denied error. The only way I have found is setting the permissions like this:

```
chown -Rf www-data.www-data /var/www/
```

So this fixes that problem, but creates another one. Now I cannot save any files to my server via ftp on my ide.

I'm a bit new to this and don't fully understand the difference between the two ways of setting permissions. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Not a dupe. I've done my research. This is not an issue about using sudo in /var/www. I'm getting permission denied errors when generating and trying to save images to a specific directory using GD Lib.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `write_enable` to be able to write files to your FTP server.

Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and Type:

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Change the line:

```
#write_enable=YES
```

To this:

```
write_enable=YES
```

Make sure you have:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

And add the following parameter:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Then, Restart:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```